# Mostrar dígitos pares de un numero de 3 dígitos

Tags: java, array

Necesito ayuda con este ejercicio.:
EJERCICIO 5
"Crear una aplicación que permita poblar un arreglo de tamaño N, con números de 3 dígitos, imprimir solo los números cuyo dígito del medio es par".

De momento , me está faltando la parte de capturar el número y recorrer sus dígitos para ver si el 2do es par.
Otra cosa, es saber si hay alguna forma de limitar el JOptionPane, para que solo permita los 3 dígitos.

Adjunto lo que he avanzado.
Desde ya gracias por la ayuda.

```
package ejercicio__5;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Francisco
 */
public class Ejercicio__5 {


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String texto = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el largo de Arreglo");
        int tam = Integer.parseInt(texto);

        int arreglo[] = new int[tam];

        llenarArreglo(arreglo);
        mostraArreglo(arreglo);
        imprimirPares(arreglo);
    }

    public static void llenarArreglo(int elemento[]) {
        int p = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < elemento.length; i++) {
            p = p + 1;
            String texto = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese número de 3 dígitos para el valor " + p + " del Arreglo");
            elemento[i] = Integer.parseInt(texto);
        }
    }

    public static void mostraArreglo(int elemento[]) {
        System.out.println("VALORES DEL ARREGLO");
        System.out.print("{");
        for (int x = 0; x < elemento.length; x++) {
            System.out.print(" " + elemento[x] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("}");
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    public static void imprimirPares(int arr1[]) {
        int num, primero, segundo, tercero;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el dígito de en medio debes convertir tu número a `String` y usar el método [`charAt()`](http://www.w3api.com/wiki/Java:String.charAt()). 
Para convertir el segundo dígito a entero usas `Integer.parseInt();`
Por último para saber si es par usar el operador `%` que devuelve el **modulo(residuo)** de una división, por lo tanto si al dividir un número entre dos no sobra nada, quiere decir que el número es par.

```
    public static void imprimirPares(int arr1[]) {
          for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){ 
     int segundo=Integer.parseInt(arr1[i].charAt(1)+"");
if(segundo%2==0)
System.out.println(arr1[i]);
    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de imprimir pares, recorres el array con los números, y por cada número le dices que haga esto:

```
int  num = 123;
String numero = num.toString();
print(numero[1]);
```

num y número yo los declararía fuera del for.

123 sería el número que tu tienes en la posición del array.

Esto no te hará las comprobaciones, lógicamente, pero te saca el número del medio.